# Is it possible to use Google Cloud NAT for VMs behind a TCP/Proxy LB so that all servers can utilize egress from a single IP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nat, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to use the Google Cloud NAT on a set of VMs running on Compute Engine which are in their own specific subnet such that all of the servers make requests to customer websites from a single static IP address. Unfortunately when I add these VMs to a TCP/SSL Proxy LB they don't appear to be using the NAT which I believe is configured correctly.

I have tried configuring the TCP Proxy LB as well as an HTTP(S) LB and the Cloud NAT and when I try and make an egress http request it results in a timeout. The ingress via the LB is working properly. The VM instances do not have external IPs which is a requirement for the Cloud NAT.

I expect the http requests to hit the server and for the web-server to make outbound http request via the Cloud NAT such that other servers need only whitelist a single IP address (a static IP assigned to the Cloud NAT)

Comment: Hi Bryan it would help us to give you more feedback if we can see an example (scrub the actual egress IPs) of your NAT. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to understand why would you need Cloud NAT in this scenario, since a TCP/SSL proxy load balancer will connect to the backends using a private conneciton and the backends won't be exposed to the Internet. Configuring just a TCP/SSL proxy would be enough for your scenario imo.
The following official documentation will explain my point[1](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#nat-not-performed):

> Backend VMs for HTTP(S), SSL Proxy, and TCP Proxy load balancers do
>   not need external IP addresses themselves, nor do they need Cloud NAT
>   to send replies to the load balancer. HTTP(S), SSL Proxy, and TCP
>   Proxy load balancers communicate with backend VMs using their primary
>   internal IP addresses.